# How retrieve each specific column's values by looping through rows using C# from excel?

Tags: c#, vba, excel, syncfusion

I am editing uploaded excel workbooks using C# with the same logic I used to do using VBA. I am using SyncFusion to open the workbooks but however, the code below is not letting me read the whole column to apply the logic. Why?

```
public void AppendID(string excelFilePath, HttpResponse response)
{

    using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
    {

        IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
        application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2007;
        IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);
        workbook.Version = ExcelVersion.Excel97to2003;
        workbook.Allow3DRangesInDataValidation = true;

        //Accessing worksheet via name

        IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[2];
```

When I try to define the range, the error will appear "Two names not allowed".

```
        var prismaID = worksheet.UsedRange["C15:C"].Value;
        var type = worksheet.UsedRange["F15:F"].Value;
        var placements = worksheet.UsedRange["I15:I"].Value;

        if (!type.Contains("PKG"))
        {
            placements = placements + prismaID;
        }

        worksheet.Range["G7"].Text = "Testing";

        workbook.SaveAs(excelFilePath);
        workbook.Close();

    }
}
```

### Logic:

Let's say I have three columns and how to use the following logic to manipulate usedRange cells?

```
ID    Condition   Name        Output
1       Yes       Sarah        Sarah(1)
2       No        George       George
3       Yes       John(3)      John(3)
```

The logics to apply:

1. Move the first column 'ID' to the end of the column 'Name' but
2. **if** Column 'Condition' contains 'No'then don't move the first column
3. **or** if it contains the same 'ID' already.

Here is the VBA code:

```vb
With xlSheet  
    LastRow = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set target = .Range(.Cells(15, 9), .Cells(LastRow, 9))
    values = target.Value

    Set ptype=.Range(.Cells(15,6),.Cells(LastRow,6))
    pvalues=ptype.Value

    For i = LBound(values, 1) To UBound(values, 1)
        'if Statement for test keywords
        If InStr(1,pvalues(i,1),"Package")= 0 AND InStr(1,pvalues(i,1),"Roadblock")= 0 Then 
            If Instr(values(I,1),.Cells(i + 15 - LBound(values, 1), 3)) = 0 Then
            'If InStr(1,values(i,1),"(")=0 Then
                values(i, 1) = values(i, 1) & "(" & .Cells(i + 15 - LBound(values, 1), 3) & ")"
            End If 
        End If
    Next

    target.Value = values
End With
```

Comment: What does it mean `UsedRange["C15:C"]`? How can a range be from C15 to column C?

Comment: @alex-butenko If Range does not apply to column, what will work to retrieve column's values?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand, what did you mean there. And also, where exactly error happens (what kind of error it is - exception?)

Comment: yes. the error was exception. I just wanted to get columns and its values.  something like this:  
        for (int i = 1; i <= range.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myrange = myworksheet.get_Range(/*your column letter, ex: "A" or "B"*/ + i.ToString(), System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            string temp = myrange.Text;
            if(temp.Contains("YES"))
            {
                //Do your YES logic
            }
            else if(temp.Contains("NO"))
            {
               
            }
        }

Comment: "exception" means there is an error but you didn't tell us **which** error you get. We need a exact error message. Also code in comments is pretty much unreadable, therefore always try to [edit] your original question to add code.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be achieved by appending column ID with column Name using XlsIO.

Please refer below code snippet for the same.

Code Snippet:

```
for(int row = 1; row<= worksheet.Columns[1].Count; row++) 
    { 
        if (worksheet[row, 2].Value == "yes" && !worksheet[row, 3].Value.EndsWith(")")) 
            worksheet[row, 4].Value = worksheet[row, 3].Value + "(" + worksheet[row, 1].Value + ")"; 
        else 
            worksheet[row, 4].Value = worksheet[row, 3].Value; 
    }
```

We have prepared simple sample and the sample can be downloaded from the following link.

Sample Link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Sample859524528.zip

I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 1):

So I am working with templates in excel, and I developed this logic.

I create a coupling of the first row of column names and the rows using the first cell as the key to bind the data in groups to a multi value dictionary.
I use the below function, which can be adapted to skip rows before parsing allowing you to target the proper row for binding. Book is ExcelDataReader.AsDataSet()

```
    public static MultiValueDictionary<string, ILookup<string, string>> ParseTemplate(string Sheet, ref List<string> keys)
    {
        int xskip = 0;
        MultiValueDictionary<string, ILookup<string, string>> mvd = new MultiValueDictionary<string, ILookup<string, string>>();

        var sheetRows = Book.Tables[Sheet];
        //Parse First row
        var FirstRow = sheetRows.Rows[0];

        for (var Columns = 0; Columns < sheetRows.Columns.Count; Columns++)
        {
            if (xskip == 0)
            {
                xskip = 1;
                continue;
            }
            keys.Add(FirstRow[Columns].ToString());
        }
        //Skip First Row
        xskip = 0;
        //Create a binding of first row and all subsequent rows
        foreach (var row in sheetRows.Select().Skip(1))
        {
            //Make the key the first cell of each row
            var key = row[0];
            List<string> rows = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                if (xskip == 0)
                {
                    xskip = 1;
                    continue;
                }
                rows.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            mvd.Add(key.ToString(), keys.Zip(rows, (m, n) => new { Key = m, Value = n }).ToLookup(x => x.Key, y => y.Value));
            xskip = 0;
        }
        return mvd;
    }

}

//This is example of what a function to parse this could do.
foreach(var Key in mvd.Keys)
{
     var KeywithValues = mvd[Key];
     foreach(ColumnName in Keys)
     {
         KeywithValues[ColumnName].
     }
}
```

Hope it helps.